# Make fieldset half the witdth in admin

Tags: admin, forms, ee-1.11, fieldsets

How can I make a fieldset to be half of the width? I want to show two fieldsets in a row in a particular page that I created in Magento's admin.

My code looks like this for now:

```
$fieldset_brand = $form->addFieldset('brand_fieldset', array(
                'legend' => $this->__('Brand categories'),
                'class' => 'fieldset-wide',
            ));
```

Any ideeas?
Or at least, from what I see, this is not quite a fieldset. It generates two div for title bar and the actual content. Is there a way to set a wrapper around those?

Any help is welcomed :)

Comment: you can assign the desired width for the fieldset like 'width' => 150px,

Comment: It does not work unfortunetly

Answer (score 2):

Add 'fieldset_container_id' to array lake this (there is no fieldset_container_class):

```
$fieldset_brand = $form->addFieldset('brand_fieldset', array(
                'legend' => $this->__('Brand categories'),                
                'fieldset_container_id' => 'fieldset_brand_container',
            ));
```

then in css use:

```
#fieldset_brand_container{float: left; width: 49%;}
#fieldset_another_container{float: right; width: 49%;}
```

Comment: # was deleted from css